# Inductor and inductive impedance

Tags: electric-circuits, inductance

In a purely inductive circuit supplied by a AC voltage source the inductive impedance offers resistance to the flow of current. So there must  be some power loss like a normal resistor ($I^2R$) does in a circuit. But the power loss is $0$. How is this possible? In which form is energy lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So there must be some power loss like a normal resistor ($I^2R$)
>    does in a circuit.  But the power loss is $0$.  How is this possible?

Suppose the voltage $V(t)$ supplied by the AC voltage is
$$V(t)=\hat{V}\cos(\omega t). \tag{1}$$

As you know, a resistor (with resistance $R$) is described by $V(t)=RI(t)$.
Quite different from that,
an ideal inductor (with [inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance) $L$) is described by the differential equation 
$$V(t)=L\frac{dI(t)}{dt}. \tag{2}$$

Plugging (1) into differential equation (2)
and solving for the current $I(t)$ you get
$$I(t)=\frac{\hat{V}}{\omega L}\sin(\omega t). \tag{3}$$

From (1) and (3) you can calculate the power delivered to the inductor.
$$\begin{align}
P(t)&=V(t)I(t) \\
&=\frac{\hat{V}^2}{\omega L} \cos(\omega t) \sin(\omega t) \\
&=\frac{\hat{V}^2}{2\omega L} \sin(2\omega t)
\end{align} \tag{4}$$

From (4) you can see that the power is oscillating between positive and negative,
and its average is $0$. So there is no power loss. The energy is only
moving back and forth between the AC voltage source and the inductor.

This is very different from a resistor ($R$)
where the power $P(t)$ is always positive, and hence the heat energy
in the resistor grows and grows with time.

> In which form is energy lost?

As explained above there is no energy loss.
But asking for the form of energy in the inductor is still a good question.

The [energy of the inductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#Self-inductance_and_magnetic_energy) is the energy of the magnetic field
in and around the inductor. It can be calculated by
$$E=\frac{1}{2}LI^2. \tag{5}$$
Plugging the current $I(t)$ from (3) into this formula (5),
you will see that the energy $E(t)$ oscillates between $0$ and a maximal value.

Comment: We say that the average value of sin(2wt) is 0 for one complete cycle (0 - 2pi/w) hence average power is 0 but what if we talk about some random interval say, 0- 3pi/4w ,here we won't get average power 0 .so do we say some power is consumed by inductor like a resistor?

Comment: @sakshidwivedi You're right, $0$ is the *average* power.
In short time intervals the inductor consumes energy,
in other short time intervals the inductor delivers energy.
But the resistor consumes all the time.
Therefore I would not say "the inductor consumes like a resistor".

Comment: @sakshidwivedi, we don't say the inductor consumes power, we say it stores energy. Because any energy that goes in to the inductor can be recovered from it later.

Comment: Okay, so what does inductive impedance actually mean? Is it present in ac circuit just to reduce current flowing through the circuit by hampering the flow of electrons? I am not able to visualize it.

Comment: @sakshidwivedi Since the impedance is $ωL$, you can use an inductor to hamper high AC frequencies but let pass DC and low AC frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

There is no loss since the current and voltage are not in phase like in a normal resistor. An inductivity shifts the phase difference from $0$ (pure $R$) to $\frac{1}{2} \pi$ (pure inductivity). Thus multiplying and adding (integrating)  both voltage and current over an integer number of periods yields $0$ energy. The energy is stored in the field and is moving back and forth between power source and inductivity.

The complex impedance of an inductively is a $j\omega L$, $j \cdot j = -1$, $\omega = 2 \cdot \pi \cdot freq$, $L$ is the inductivity. The power would be $I \cdot I \cdot jwL$, which has no real part, i.e. the real power is $0$.